# How to make a post request to box.com API with laravel?

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel

I'm trying to make a post request from my controller to the Box.com API. The request will upload a file to my Box.com account. The following code is on my view:

```
<form action="/accept" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <input type="file" name="filename">
    <input type="text" name="parent_id" value="0">

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In my controller, I'm not getting any clue of how can I send the post request to the box.com API which will send the form data with an authorization header. The Box.com API require the authorization header to accept the request.

However, in Laravel documentation they've a section where I found the following code:

```
return response($content)
        ->header('Content-Type', application/json)
        ->header('Authorization', 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
```

I can set the authorization header using this however, how the form data would be send then?

Here's the Box.com API URL to accept the post request:

```
https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely agree with pespantelis, using a `PHP HTTP Client` like [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) is a great way to go with what you wish to do.

Once you're all set up it is just a matter of formatting your request, e.g you could do what you're trying to do like so:

```
Route::get( '/', function ()
{
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client( ["base_uri" => "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/"] );

    $response = $client->request( "GET", "files/content", ["headers" => ["Authorization" => "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "Content-Type" => "application/json"]] );

    return Response::json($response);
} );
```

Although I would consider using the [Official SDK](https://github.com/crocodoc/php-box-view) or the [Community-Built SDK](https://github.com/donutdan4114/box-view-api) as pespantelis suggests as that may be easier to grasp since they lay it all out for you.

Answer (score 1):

To integrate with web services (like box.com), you should need a `PHP HTTP Client` (like [guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org)) to send `HTTP Requests`.

It's a good solution to use the [Official SDK](https://github.com/crocodoc/php-box-view) or the [Community-Built SDK](https://github.com/donutdan4114/box-view-api) for php.